# Occurrence of alphabets in a command line argument

Tags: c++

I'm having some difficulty with the argv pointer. Using *argv[1] gives me the argc count and *argv[2] the entire argument. Shouldn't each element, when dereferenced give one character?

Thanks

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    char store[10]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};int freq[10]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};int flag=0;int count=0;int t;
    for(int i=0,j=0;i<argc;i++)
    {
        for(int z=0;z<count;z++)
        {   
        if(i==0) break;
            if(*argv[i+2]==store[z]) flag=1;t=z;break;
        }
           if(flag==0||i==0) {store[j]=*argv[i+2];j++; count++;}
           else freq[t]+=1;
           flag=0;
    }
    for(int x=0;x<count;x++) cout<<store[x]<<"\t"<<freq[x]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it should. But, argv[1] points to the first argument string. argv[2] to the second, and so on. Until argv[argc-1] which is the last argument passed to your program. So what did you expect from `*argv[i+2]`?

Comment: I don't think this does what you expect it to do: `if(*argv[i]==store[z]) flag=1;t=z;break;`. You should format your code more properly, it'd be less error prone and more readable for external users.

Comment: *argv[2] should give the first character of the second argument I entered and so on right?

Comment: By the way, to make your question better, please tell us what the actual arguments are, what output you are getting and what output you are expecting. For the actual output, please copy-paste it into the question.

Comment: I'm getting a segmentation fault again wtf is happening ;(

Comment: You getting the segfault at `*argv[i+2]` when `i` reaches `argc-2` because then you would access the argument string `argv[argc]` which is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You getting the segfault at `*argv[i+2]` when `i` reaches `argc-2` because then you would access the argument string `argv[argc]` which is not defined.

If you want to iterate through the characters of an argument, you should use a two-dimensional access, e.g.:

```
// assume there are two arguments present (argc == 3)
int len = 5; // assume there a 5 chars in argv[2]
for(int k = 0; k < len; k++) {
  // do something for each char
  if(argv[2][k] == 'x') { ... }
}
```

EDIT: changed example to `argv[2]` holding the string.